# Can I use "dou" to offer something?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I understand that "dou" means how, and for example おちゃはどうですか means that I'm asking how is the tea? But, in Busuu app it says that I can use the same question to offer something, as if I'm asking "how about a tea?" I'm not really sure about this last thing so I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: 明鏡国語辞典 dictionary: 相手に勧める語。いかが。「─、一緒に行かないか」「もう一つ─ですか」. I hope this helps.

Comment: @LonelyDriver Your comment is correct, however I'm not sure the OP will understand if they're a beginner when it comes to Japanese.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, ～はどうですか can be used in several ways.

1. "How is ～?"

   > 最近彼はどうですか?
   > How is he doing recently?
   >
   > 日本はどうですか?
   > How is Japan? / How do you like Japan? / How is your stay in Japan?
2. "How/What about ～?" (suggestion, offering)

   > お茶はどうですか?
   > How about some tea?
   >
   > 日本はどうですか?
   > How about (going to) Japan? / What about Japan?
3. "How/What about ～?" (asking the same thing for another topic)

   > 私は元気です。あなたはどうですか?
   > I'm fine. How about you?
   >
   > こちらはとても寒いです。日本はどうですか?
   > It's very cold here. How about Japan?